# InvalidOperationException: Can't compile a NewExpression with a constructor declared on an abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

Getting an error when trying to retrieve objects from mongodb:

> InvalidOperationException: Can't compile a NewExpression with a
>   constructor declared on an abstract class

My class is:

```
public class App 
{
    public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Feature
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteFeature : Feature
{
    public string ConcreteProp { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure why it is having issues with abstractions. I see, mongodb recorded `_t: "ConcreteFeature"` type name, it has everything to deserialize it. I have no constructor in abstract class.

Ideas?

Comment: Even with "_t" in the database, you need to tell Mongo that `ConcreteFeature` is derived from `Feature`. Since you don't have `[BsonKnownTypes(...)]`, do you have  a mapping configured?

Comment: @John that's exactly it. Please see my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I needed to list "KnownTypes" for BsonClassMap to make it work:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Feature>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIsRootClass(true);

    var featureType = typeof(Feature);
    featureType.Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(type => featureType.IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList()
        .ForEach(type => cm.AddKnownType(type));
});
```

This way you won't need to touch the code even if you add new types as long as they are in 1 assembly. More info [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/).

Answer (score 5):

1.On Abstract class Use

```
[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(ConcreteFeature)]
public abstract class Feature
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class ConcreteFeature : Feature
{
    public string ConcreteProp { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never going to store your abstract class directly in the database. The whole known types stuff is just if you need the inheritance tree in the type discriminator which is typically overkill.  The serializer does need to know about your concrete classes in advance though so the below will suffice.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ConcreteFeature>();
```

Assuming you're going to be adding child classes regularly then you can use reflection and register them that way.